# Sleep script: Not executed via pm-hibernate

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, systemd, hibernate

I've written a script which is should be executed before and after hibernation (see below) on a stationary PC (no notebook). The script unloads and reloads DVB and network modules and is placed in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/40_devb_reload.sh`
This script works if I initiate the hibernation via the GUI of the installed Kubuntu 19.04 system. But if I execute the command `sudo pm-hibernate` in the terminal or a python script is executing this command (`check_output("sudo pm-hibernate", shell=True)`), the hibernation script are not executed (verified via the log file the script is writing) but the hibernation itself works.
The first approach would be to just execute the script before hibernation. But the python script i am using has no root privileges, so the execution has to be initiated by the system.
Note (I don't know if this is relevant): I allowed the specific user "media" to execute `sudo pm-hibernate` without entering a root password through an entry in `etc/sudoers.d/`.

The question now is: how can a bash/python script enter hibernation with execution of sleep scripts?

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")


echo "$timestamp: DVB suspend script started." >> /home/media/Profile/Scripts/suspend.log
case "$1" in  
    pre)
        /etc/init.d/tvheadend stop
        rmmod ddbridge
        rmmod cxd2841er 
        rmmod dvb_core

        echo "$timestamp: Modules unloaded." >> /home/media/Profile/Scripts/suspend.log
        ;;
    post)
        #restart network driver due hibernate issue on ubuntu 19
        rmmod e1000e
        modprobe e1000e
        modprobe dvb_core
        modprobe cxd2841er
        modprobe ddbridge
        /etc/init.d/tvheadend start
        echo "$timestamp: Modules reloaded." >> /home/media/Profile/Scripts/suspend.log
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Is your `$HOME` directory encrypted? Try putting your log messages in `/tmp`, or `/var/run`.

Comment: if `ll /lib/systemd/system-sleep/40_devb_reload.sh` doesn't reveal an `x` for all users then: `sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/40_devb_reload.sh`

Comment: Nothing encrypted in system. Logs written to /tmp/suspend.log, no changes.
`ls -al` on `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` shows: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   895 Mai 18 18:14 40_dvb_reload.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found a solution:
Rather than calling `sudo pm-hibernate`, using `sudo systemctl hibernate` seems to trigger all side effects, including execution of scripts in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`
This works in terminal as well as in my python calls above.